# Cannot update one field on firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, updates

I cannot update one field on firebase, when i do delete all the others fields of the database

CODE

```
        String URL_EVENT_REFERENCE = "eventmodel";
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseEvent = database.getReference(URL_EVENT_REFERENCE);
        String key = "KTVAt0NM1Y5v32YxSqc";          
        Map<String, Object> eventValues = new HashMap<>();
        eventValues.put("name", "new name");    
        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put(key, eventValues); 
        databaseEvent.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

This is the JSON tree, on the eventmodel y want to update the -KTVAt0NM1Y5v32YxSqc and change the name hola to new name

```html
{
  "eventmodel" : {
    "-KTVAt0NM1Y5v32YxSqc" : {
      "info" : "",
      "limit" : 2,
      "members" : {
        "Mn7gZ7rn5XRGU1HXujbbSQv05BH2" : true
      },
      "name" : "hola",
      "pic" : "default_publish_img",
      "place" : {
        "address" : "Barcelona, España",
        "latitude" : 41.3850639,
        "longitude" : 2.1734034999999494
      },
      "status" : true,
      "timeCurrentEnd" : "7/10/2016 21:27",
      "timeCurrentStart" : "7/10/2016 20:27",
      "uidLeader" : "Mn7gZ7rn5XRGU1HXujbbSQv05BH2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting new empty object with only name field..

try to update only the name instead of the whole object

```
databaseEvent.child(key).child("name").setValue("new name");
```

Comment: Yes but is how to explain on the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: what? I don't understand your question.. and my answer is listed in your doc link..

Comment: does not matter! it's okey your answer